# Get coordinates of the given text in pdf using python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I am working on a project where I need to parse PDF with python. I have gone through many answers in StackOverflow regarding this but none of them suits my need perfectly. I want to get the coordinates of a text in pdf by using python script. If I provide a pdf and "some_sample_text", the script should search inside the pdf and provide the x,y coordinates of  "some_sample_text". I know that Apache pdfbox does this nicely. I need something like Apache pdfbox or a python library for the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(disclaimer: I am the author of `pText`, the library used in this answer.)

We're going to start by loading the `Document`

```
    with open("input.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        l = RegularExpressionTextExtraction("[sS]orbitol")
        doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])
```

The syntax is quite straightforward. `PDF.loads` attempts to read an input stream, and process it as a PDF. You can optionally specify an array of `EventListener` objects. `EventListener` is notified during parsing whenever text, images, pages are rendered.

In this example we're passing a `RegularExpressionTextExtraction`. This implementation of `EventListener` monitors all incoming text-rendering commands, and attempts to match them against a regular expression.

Finally, once the `Document` has been loaded, we can extract all matches. In this example, I'm going to output them as a json array.

```
        # export matches
        with open("output.json", "w") as json_file_handle:
            obj = [
                {
                    "text": x.text,
                    "x0": int(x.get_baseline().x),
                    "y0": int(x.get_baseline().y),
                    "width": int(x.get_baseline().width),
                    "height": int(x.get_baseline().height),
                }
                for x in l.get_matched_chunk_of_text_render_events_per_page(0)
            ]
            json_file_handle.write(json.dumps(obj, indent=4))
```

I also made an example where the matched letters are marked in the PDF.

[image]

You can obtain pText either on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release), or using [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ptext-joris-schellekens/)
There are a ton more [examples](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md), check them out to find out more about working with text.

Answer (score -1):

This package says it can do it.  I don't know how out of date it is.

https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/

Comment: Please refrain from giving answers that consist solely of a link. At least copy/paste a relevant example from their documentation.